# Attempt to index field (a nil value), for an Object

Tags: lua, love2d

I have a problem with trying to add things to a LOVE2D version of Match-3. (From the CS50 course)

I added a function `swapTiles()` into my `Board` class and made a class object called `self.board` in a Class called `PlayState`. Then when I try to access the new function, it says this error:

```
Error

src/states/PlayState.lua:155: attempt to index field 'board' (a nil value)
```

I'll provide my Board and PlayState class below:

Board: (keep in mind the new function is literally in the code)

```
Board = Class{}

function Board:init(x, y, level) -- Added "level" as an integer for the block variations.
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.matches = {}
    self.level = level

    self:initializeTiles()
end

function Board:swapTiles(tile1, tile2)
    -- swap grid positions of tiles
    local tempX = tile1.gridX
    local tempY = tile1.gridY

    tile1.gridX = tile2.gridX
    tile1.gridY = tile2.gridY
    tile2.gridX = tempX
    tile2.gridY = tempY

    -- swap tiles in the tiles table
    self.tiles[tile1.gridY][tile1.gridX] = tile1

    self.tiles[tile2.gridY][tile2.gridX] = tile2

end

function Board:initializeTiles()
    self.tiles = {}

    -- There should only be two shiny tiles.

    for tileY = 1, 8 do
        
        -- empty table that will serve as a new row
        table.insert(self.tiles, {})

        for tileX = 1, 8 do

            
            self.isPowerup = false
            if math.random(1, 25) == 4 then
                self.isPowerup = true
            end
            -- create a new tile at X,Y with a random color and variety
            table.insert(self.tiles[tileY], Tile(tileX, tileY, math.random(18), math.min(8, math.random(1, self.level)), self.isPowerup))
        end
    end

    while self:calculateMatches() do
        -- recursively initialize if matches were returned so we always have
        -- a matchless board on start
        self:initializeTiles()
    end
end



--[[
    Goes left to right, top to bottom in the board, calculating matches by counting consecutive
    tiles of the same color. Doesn't need to check the last tile in every row or column if the 
    last two haven't been a match.
]]
function Board:calculateMatches()
    local matches = {}

    -- how many of the same color blocks in a row we've found
    local matchNum = 1

    -- horizontal matches first
    for y = 1, 8 do
        local colorToMatch = self.tiles[y][1].color

        matchNum = 1
        
        -- every horizontal tile
        for x = 2, 8 do
            -- if this is the same color as the one we're trying to match...
            if self.tiles[y][x].color == colorToMatch then
                matchNum = matchNum + 1
            else
                -- set this as the new color we want to watch for
                colorToMatch = self.tiles[y][x].color

                -- if we have a match of 3 or more up to now, add it to our matches table
                if matchNum >= 3 then
                    local match = {}

                    -- go backwards from here by matchNum
                    for x2 = x - 1, x - matchNum, -1 do
                        -- add each tile to the match that's in that match
                        table.insert(match, self.tiles[y][x2])

                        -- Shiny Check
                       if self.tiles[y][x2].isShiny == true then
                        for i = 1, 8 do
                            table.insert(match, self.tiles[y][i])
                        end
                       end
                    end

                    -- add this match to our total matches table
                    table.insert(matches, match)
                end

                -- don't need to check last two if they won't be in a match
                if x >= 7 then
                    break
                end

                matchNum = 1
            end
        end

        -- account for the last row ending with a match
        if matchNum >= 3 then
            local match = {}
            
            -- go backwards from end of last row by matchNum
            for x = 8, 8 - matchNum + 1, -1 do
                table.insert(match, self.tiles[y][x])
            end

            table.insert(matches, match)
        end
    end

    -- vertical matches
    for x = 1, 8 do
        local colorToMatch = self.tiles[1][x].color

        matchNum = 1

        -- every vertical tile
        for y = 2, 8 do
            if self.tiles[y][x].color == colorToMatch then
                matchNum = matchNum + 1
            else
                colorToMatch = self.tiles[y][x].color

                if matchNum >= 3 then
                    local match = {}

                    for y2 = y - 1, y - matchNum, -1 do
                        table.insert(match, self.tiles[y2][x])

                        if self.tiles[y2][x].isShiny == true then
                            for i = 1, 8 do
                                table.insert(match, self.tiles[i][x])
                            end
                        end
                    end

                    table.insert(matches, match)
                end

                matchNum = 1

                -- don't need to check last two if they won't be in a match
                if y >= 7 then
                    break
                end
            end
        end

        -- account for the last column ending with a match
        if matchNum >= 3 then
            local match = {}

           
            
            -- go backwards from end of last row by matchNum
            for y = 8, 8 - matchNum, -1 do

              

                table.insert(match, self.tiles[y][x])
            end

            table.insert(matches, match)
        end
    end

    -- store matches for later reference
    self.matches = matches

    -- return matches table if > 0, else just return false
    return #self.matches > 0 and self.matches or false
end

--[[
    Remove the matches from the Board by just setting the Tile slots within
    them to nil, then setting self.matches to nil.
]]
function Board:removeMatches()
    for k, match in pairs(self.matches) do
        for k, tile in pairs(match) do
            self.tiles[tile.gridY][tile.gridX] = nil
        end
    end

    self.matches = nil
end

--[[
    Shifts down all of the tiles that now have spaces below them, then returns a table that
    contains tweening information for these new tiles.
]]
function Board:getFallingTiles()
    -- tween table, with tiles as keys and their x and y as the to values
    local tweens = {}

    -- for each column, go up tile by tile till we hit a space
    for x = 1, 8 do
        local space = false
        local spaceY = 0

        local y = 8
        while y >= 1 do
            -- if our last tile was a space...
            local tile = self.tiles[y][x]
            
            if space then
                -- if the current tile is *not* a space, bring this down to the lowest space
                if tile then
                    -- put the tile in the correct spot in the board and fix its grid positions
                    self.tiles[spaceY][x] = tile
                    tile.gridY = spaceY

                    -- set its prior position to nil
                    self.tiles[y][x] = nil

                    -- tween the Y position to 32 x its grid position
                    tweens[tile] = {
                        y = (tile.gridY - 1) * 32
                    }

                    -- set space back to 0, set Y to spaceY so we start back from here again
                    space = false
                    y = spaceY
                    spaceY = 0
                end
            elseif tile == nil then
                space = true
                
                if spaceY == 0 then
                    spaceY = y
                end
            end

            y = y - 1
        end
    end

    -- create replacement tiles at the top of the screen
    for x = 1, 8 do
        for y = 8, 1, -1 do
            local tile = self.tiles[y][x]

            -- if the tile is nil, we need to add a new one
            if not tile then
                local tile = Tile(x, y, math.random(18), math.random(1, self.level))
                tile.y = -32
                self.tiles[y][x] = tile

                tweens[tile] = {
                    y = (tile.gridY - 1) * 32
                }
            end
        end
    end

    return tweens
end

function Board:getNewTiles()
    return {}
end

function Board:testForMatches()
    for y = 1, 8 do

        for x = 1, 8 do

            -- Test for left swap
            if x > 1 then
                
            end

        end

    end
end

function Board:render()
    for y = 1, #self.tiles do
        for x = 1, #self.tiles[1] do
            self.tiles[y][x]:render(self.x, self.y)
        end
    end
end
```

Here's my PlayState: (look for PlayState:swapTiles(), keep in mind that the self.board is being used several times for and works fine, except when i try calling self.board:swapTiles().)

```
PlayState = Class{__includes = BaseState}

function PlayState:init()
    -- start our transition alpha at full, so we fade in
    self.transitionAlpha = 255

    -- position in the grid which we're highlighting
    self.boardHighlightX = 0
    self.boardHighlightY = 0

    -- timer used to switch the highlight rect's color
    self.rectHighlighted = false

    -- flag to show whether we're able to process input (not swapping or clearing)
    self.canInput = true

    -- tile we're currently highlighting (preparing to swap)
    self.highlightedTile = nil

    self.score = 0
    self.timer = 60

    -- set our Timer class to turn cursor highlight on and off
    Timer.every(0.5, function()
        self.rectHighlighted = not self.rectHighlighted
    end)

    -- subtract 1 from timer every second
    Timer.every(1, function()
        self.timer = self.timer - 1

        -- play warning sound on timer if we get low
        if self.timer <= 5 then
            gSounds['clock']:play()
        end
    end)
end

function PlayState:enter(params)
    -- grab level # from the params we're passed
    self.level = params.level

    -- spawn a board and place it toward the right
    self.board = params.board or Board(VIRTUAL_WIDTH - 272, 16)

    -- grab score from params if it was passed
    self.score = params.score or 0

    -- score we have to reach to get to the next level
    self.scoreGoal = self.level * 1.25 * 1000
end

function PlayState:update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.wasPressed('escape') then
        love.event.quit()
    end

    -- go back to start if time runs out
    if self.timer <= 0 then
        -- clear timers from prior PlayStates
        Timer.clear()
        
        gSounds['game-over']:play()

        gStateMachine:change('game-over', {
            score = self.score
        })
    end

    -- go to next level if we surpass score goal
    if self.score >= self.scoreGoal then
        -- clear timers from prior PlayStates
        -- always clear before you change state, else next state's timers
        -- will also clear!
        Timer.clear()

        gSounds['next-level']:play()

        -- change to begin game state with new level (incremented)
        gStateMachine:change('begin-game', {
            level = self.level + 1,
            score = self.score
        })
    end

    if self.canInput then
        -- move cursor around based on bounds of grid, playing sounds
        if love.keyboard.wasPressed('up') then
            self.boardHighlightY = math.max(0, self.boardHighlightY - 1)
            gSounds['select']:play()
        elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('down') then
            self.boardHighlightY = math.min(7, self.boardHighlightY + 1)
            gSounds['select']:play()
        elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('left') then
            self.boardHighlightX = math.max(0, self.boardHighlightX - 1)
            gSounds['select']:play()
        elseif love.keyboard.wasPressed('right') then
            self.boardHighlightX = math.min(7, self.boardHighlightX + 1)
            gSounds['select']:play()
        end

        -- if we've pressed enter, to select or deselect a tile...
        if love.keyboard.wasPressed('enter') or love.keyboard.wasPressed('return') then
            -- if same tile as currently highlighted, deselect
            local x = self.boardHighlightX + 1
            local y = self.boardHighlightY + 1
            
            -- if nothing is highlighted, highlight current tile
            if not self.highlightedTile then
                self.highlightedTile = self.board.tiles[y][x]

            -- if we select the position already highlighted, remove highlight
            elseif self.highlightedTile == self.board.tiles[y][x] then
                self.highlightedTile = nil

            -- if the difference between X and Y combined of this highlighted tile
            -- vs the previous is not equal to 1, also remove highlight
            elseif math.abs(self.highlightedTile.gridX - x) + math.abs(self.highlightedTile.gridY - y) > 1 then
                gSounds['error']:play()
                self.highlightedTile = nil
            else
                self:swapTiles(self.highlightedTile, self.board.tiles[y][x], true)
            end
        end
    end

    Timer.update(dt)
end


function PlayState:swapTiles(tile1, tile2, swapBackAtNoMatch)

    local tile1 = tile1
    local tile2 = tile2
    local swapBackAtNoMatch = swapBackAtNoMatch

    self.board:swapTiles(tile1, tile2) -- Causes the nil error.

    if swapBackAtNoMatch then
    -- tween coordinates between two swapping tiles
    Timer.tween(0.1, {
        [tile1] = {x = tile2.x, y = tile2.y},
        [tile2] = {x = tile1.x, y = tile1.y}
    })

    -- once they've swapped, tween falling blocks
    :finish(function ()

        local matches = self.board:calculateMatches()
        if matches then
            self.calculateMatches(matches)
        else

            -- swap back if there's no match
            self.swapTiles(tile1, tile2, false)

            gSounds['error']:play()
        end
    end)
    else
    -- tween coordinates between the two so they swap
    Timer.tween(0.1, {
        [tile1] = {x = tile2.x, y = tile2.y},
        [tile2] = {x = tile1.x, y = tile1.y}})
    end

end

--[[
    Calculates whether any matches were found on the board and tweens the needed
    tiles to their new destinations if so. Also removes tiles from the board that
    have matched and replaces them with new randomized tiles, deferring most of this
    to the Board class.
]]
function PlayState:calculateMatches()
    self.highlightedTile = nil

    -- if we have any matches, remove them and tween the falling blocks that result
    local matches = self.board:calculateMatches()
    
    if matches then
        gSounds['match']:stop()
        gSounds['match']:play()

        -- add score for each match
        for k, match in pairs(matches) do

            local varietyPoints = 0 -- We'll keep track of the bonus variety points here
             -- We'll use vareity to calculate points for each tile within a match
             for j, tiles in pairs(match) do
                
                    varietyPoints = varietyPoints + tiles.variety * 25


            end
            
            self.score = self.score + (#match * 50) + varietyPoints

           

            -- Also add one second times the number of match to the timer
            self.timer = self.timer + #match * 1

        end

        -- remove any tiles that matched from the board, making empty spaces
        self.board:removeMatches()

        -- gets a table with tween values for tiles that should now fall
        local tilesToFall = self.board:getFallingTiles()

        -- first, tween the falling tiles over 0.25s
        Timer.tween(0.25, tilesToFall):finish(function()
            local newTiles = self.board:getNewTiles()
            
            -- then, tween new tiles that spawn from the ceiling over 0.25s to fill in
            -- the new upper gaps that exist
            Timer.tween(0.25, newTiles):finish(function()
                -- recursively call function in case new matches have been created
                -- as a result of falling blocks once new blocks have finished falling
                self:calculateMatches()
            end)
        end)
    -- if no matches, we can continue playing
    else
        self.canInput = true
    end
end
```

Honestly doesn't make much sense. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function PlayState:swapTiles(tile1, tile2, swapBackAtNoMatch) end
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
PlayState.swaptiles = function(self, tile1, tile2, swapBackAtNoMatch) end
```

That's the reason why you can work with self inside that function.

A function defined like that needs to be called using the colon operator as well to make this work. Or you explicitly provide the table as first parameter.

Hence in your call `self.swapTiles(tile1, tile2, false)`

`self` is going to be `tile1`

`tile1.board` is `nil` so `self.board` is `nil` in this function call which causes the error

You have to call `self:swapTiles(tile1, tile2, false)` or `self.swapTiles(self, tile1, tile2, false)`

Please make sure you fully understand the colon syntax.